# Border of the last child in an ul is grey (alltough i specified the border color to #FFF) instead of white, why?

Tags: html, css

This is for a topmenu for a page and i put a left border for every li-element and for the last-child of the ul i also add a righ-border. But for some reason the right-border of the last-child appears grey instead of white and I can't seem to figure out why... Thanks in advance.

```
.menu li {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;     
    background-color:#D64708;
    display:inline-block;
    border-left: 1px outset #fff;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
.menu li:last-child{
    border-right: 1px outset #fff;
}
```

complete code of the header + CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/xaxdjyy1/

(I don't know any javascript)

EDIT: had the wrong jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your border style is `outset`. An outset border is shaded differently to achieve such an effect.

If you want a pure white border, use `solid` instead of `outset`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the color, it's the outset shading that's making it appear that way. This will give you a solid white border.

```
.menu li:last-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```